# silverlight dataform from 2010 toolkit: cancel edit not working in all scenarios

Tags: silverlight, dataform

You're using a buggy control (DataForm) and call CancelEdit() and in some scenarios it doesn't cancel. You pull some of your hear out. How to workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call BeginEdit() immediately before you call CancelEdit(). Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

The object binded to your dataForm have to implement IEditableObject.
Then the CancelEdit call will work